# Subdivision Surface problem -

Tags: mesh, vertices, subdivision-surface

When I add a subdivision surface modifier to this mesh, the mesh seems to have holes in. Looks like the faces become rounded with emptiness towards the ends of the face.

Does anyone have any idea why this has happened?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the faces are not connected to each other. You can check it by going into edit mode, selecting one face and moving it, then you'll see if it's connected or loose.
If the faces are loose, you can try and select all vertices and merge by distance (set a distance that doesn't destroy any faces but will merge the vertices that are overlapping / almost overlapping.

Comment: if u provide blend file, we can check it out...

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  If Alexandre Marcati's above comment doesn't help then it'd probably be a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Any chance you're also using an Edge-split modifier?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati would you write your answer up as an actual answer?

Comment: @MartyFouts thanks, I just posted it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the faces are not connected to each other.
You can check if they are by going into edit mode, selecting one face and moving it, then you'll see if it's connected or loose.

If the faces are loose, you can try and select all vertices and merge by distance (set a small enough distance that doesn't destroy any faces but will still merge the vertices that are overlapping / almost overlapping).